# c - why does it make sense that indexing a character pointer is an int?

Tags: c, string

```
char *a = "apple";
printf("%s\n", a);  // fine
printf("%s\n", a[1]);  // compiler complains an int is being passed
```

Why does indexing a string pointer give me an int? I was expecting it to just print the string starting at position one (which is actually what happens when i use `&a[1]` instead). why do i need to get the address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's just how the `[]` operator is defined - `a[1]`, when `a` is a `char *`, fetches the next `char` after the one pointed to by `a` (`a[0]` is the first one).

The second part of the puzzle is that `char` values are always promoted to `int` (or rarely, `unsigned int`) when passed as part of a function's variable-length argument list.

`a` is equivalent to `&a[0]`, and it prints from the first character - so it makes sense that `&a[1]` would print starting from the second character.  You can also just use `a + 1` - that's completely equivalent.

If you use the `%c` conversion specifier, which prints a single character, you can use `a[1]` to print just the second character:

```
printf("%c\n", a[1]);
```

Answer (score 6):

The expression `a[1]` yields a single *char*, and in expressions that is widened to an *int*.
You can print a char with `%c`:

```
char *a = "apple";
printf("%c\n", a[1]);   // prints 'p'
```

You can achieve what you want by using `a+1`, like

```
printf("%s\n", a+1);    // prints 'pple'
```

An other way to explain this:

```
char *a2 = a+1;   // a2 points to 'pple'   
a[1] ≡ *(a+1)  ≡ *a2
```

Answer (score 2):

%s expects a char* pointer. Char alone is interpreted as an integer.
Moreover, a[1] gives you the second element, not the first!

Comment: a "char * pointer" would be a "char**" (I bet you're one of those people who say things like ATM machine!)

Comment: Our ATMs mostly say "Please wait ..."

Answer (score 2):

Characters (i.e. the kind of thing that a[1] evaluates to)  are integers, but the "%s" formatter for printf() expects a pointer. Note that the fact that this error was detected at all is an extended feature offered by some compilers - it's not part of Standard C. Other compilers would simply fail at run-time, probably with a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a = "bla"
```

`a` : is a `char*`, and you should use `%s` for `printf(...)`;

`a[1]` is equivalent to `*(a+1)`, then `a[1]` is a `char`, and you should use `%c` for `printf(...)`;

`&a[1]` is equivalent to `&(*(a+1))`, then `&a[1]` is a `char*` , and you should use `%s` for `printf(...)`;

This is more like a pointer question. To better understand how pointers work, think this way:

```
char *j;
```

`j`      is a `char*` 
`*j`     is a `char`, and equivalent with `j[0]` 
`*(j+1)` is a `char`, and equivalent with `j[1]` 
`&(*j)`  is a`char*`, and equivalent with `&j[0]`, equivalent with `j`
`&j`     is a `char**`

Another example:

```
char j**
```

`j`   is a `char**` 
`*j`  is a `char*` 
`**j` is a `char`, and equivalent with `*(*(j+0)+0)`, and equivalent with `j[0][0]`
`&j`  is a `char***`

and so on...